# Prometheus --> Getting "Server returned HTTP status 400 Bad Request" attempting scraping

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, amazon-eks, kube-state-metrics, grafana-agent

I have a Grafana Agent with Kube State Metrics in an EKS cluster and I am getting this error attempting to scrape a kubelet.
Any reason why such error can appear?

```
ts=2022-11-14T19:42:49.643418574Z caller=scrape.go:1302 
level=debug agent=prometheus instance=6adb012c62a4c8a8139b7fbf04a08668 component="scrape manager" 
scrape_pool=integrations/kubernetes/kubelet target=http://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local:443/api/v1/nodes/ip-192-168-0-8.ec2.internal/proxy/metrics 
msg="Scrape failed" 
err="server returned HTTP status 400 Bad Request"
```

Comment: `http://...:443` sure is suspicious, and this is dangerously close to [off topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); do you have a **programming** question about prometheus?